# Layer spatial reference system units EPSG::32633

Tags: qgis, python, gdalogr

I polygonized a raster with the following code:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
gdal.UseExceptions()

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(32633)

ds = gdal.Open('H:/Threshold/savi_nsdvi66.tif')
srcband = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
dst_layername = 'H:/Threshold/c11111111'
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource(dst_layername + '.shp')

dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = srs,   geom_type=ogr.wkbMultiPolygon )
polygone = gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
```

Everything works fine just one point is freaking me out. The shapefile shows the correct reference system (`+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`) in QGIS but I receive wrong layer spatial system units (xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax) dimensions from the input raster file not the usual EPSG coordinates.

Comment: what do you mean by "not the usual EPSG coordinates"? EPSG is not a unit, in this case the units would be meters

Comment: For a shapefile i want to compare with i have those values (xMin,yMin 419726.66,5852881.85 : xMax,yMax 420461.79,5853444.63) for the one from the example code i get (xMin,yMin 0,0 : xMax,yMax 10980,10980). I dont mean units i mean the extension?!

Comment: so your bounding box is wrong? is your tif georeferenced? please add the output of gdalinfo to the question

Comment: Yes youre right. For the comand
print ds.GetMetadata() i recieve {}. I wrote the raster from a numpy array before.

Comment: driver = ds.GetDriver()
outDs = driver.Create('H:/Threshold/savi_nsdvi61.tif', rows, cols, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outBand = outDs.GetRasterBand(1)
outBand.SetNoDataValue(0)
outBand.WriteArray(new2)

Comment: then that is your problem

Comment: It was thx!!!!!